# Chamar mais de um callback ao mesmo tempo

Tags: java, android, callback

Preciso que uma WorkerClass que gera números sequenciais imprima através de uma Interface Callback estes números na MainActivity e numa SegundaActivity quando aberta. O meu problema é que quando a SegundaActivity está aberta a MainActivity deixa de receber os números que estão a ser gerados na WorkerClass. Segue o meu código:

> Classe **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MeuCallback {

    private Button button1;

    private MinhaWorkerClass minhaWorkerClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        minhaWorkerClass = minhaWorkerClass.getInstancia();
        if (minhaWorkerClass != null) {
            minhaWorkerClass.criaCallback(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void imprimeNumero(int numero) {
        Log.i("Rute", "MainActivity-Numero: " + numero);
    }
}
```

> Classe **SegundaActivity**

```
public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MeuCallback {

    private MinhaWorkerClass minhaWorkerClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);

        minhaWorkerClass = minhaWorkerClass.getInstancia();
        if (minhaWorkerClass != null) {
            minhaWorkerClass.criaCallback(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void imprimeNumero(int numero) {
        Log.i("Rute", "SegundaActivity-Numero: " + numero);
    }
}
```

> Classe **MinhaWorkerClass**

```
public class MinhaWorkerClass {

    private MeuCallback meuCallback;

    private static MinhaWorkerClass instancia;

    // Construtor privado:
    private MinhaWorkerClass() {

        constroiSequenciaNumeros();
    }

    public static synchronized MinhaWorkerClass getInstancia() {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new MinhaWorkerClass();
        }

        // Retorna sempre a unica instancia criada desta Classe:
        return instancia;
    }

    public void criaCallback(MeuCallback meuCallback){
        this.meuCallback = meuCallback;
    }

    private void constroiSequenciaNumeros() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

                    if (meuCallback != null) {
                        meuCallback.imprimeNumero(i);
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

> Interface **MeuCallback**

```
public interface MeuCallback {

    void imprimeNumero(int numero);
}
```

Comment: Talvez o `EventBus` seja uma alternativa.

Comment: Isso é possível fazer com facilidade, mesmo se recorrer a qualquer api externa(EventBus). No entanto há o risco de vazamento de memória. O que vai fazer com os números que a MainActivity recebe enquanto esta não está visível?

Comment: @ramaral, necessito de abrir novas atividades mesmo que a SegundaAtividade ainda esteja aberta.

Comment: Tem de encontrar outra forma. Sem saber exactamente o que quer é impossível dar uma solução. Essa forma irá "vazar memória" sempre que uma das Activities for destruída pelo Android, por exemplo ao rodar o dispositivo.

Comment: @ramaral, esse problema vai ser controlado porque as novas Atividades vão-se auto-destruir ao fim de 4 segundos. O meu problema é a MainActivity deixar de saber quais os números que estão a ser gerados na WorkerClass sempre que uma nova atividade estiver aberta.

Comment: Não me referia às novas activities mas sim à MainActivity e à SegundaActivity.

Comment: @ramaral, o meu código aqui exposto é só um pequeno esboço do meu real projecto, e por isto, pode estar a causar alguma confusão. A quantidade de atividades que vão ser disparadas pela MainActivity serão muito poucas (+/- umas 6) que se auto-destruirão. Pedia-lhe, se possível, se me pode mostra a sua solução?

Comment: Repito: o problema não está nas "atividades que vão ser disparadas pela MainActivity" mas sim na MainActivity e em todas aquelas que usem `minhaWorkerClass.criaCallback(this)`

Comment: Certo, mas mesmo assim me deixe chegar a outras conclusões e por favor mostre-me  a sua solução para por a MainActivity a receber o Callback permanentemente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe MinhaWorkerClass, da forma como está implementada, apenas consegue registar um *callback*.

Para que possa registar mais de um tem de os guardar em um array.

```
public class MinhaWorkerClass {

    private ArrayList<MeuCallback> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
    ...

    public void addCallback(MeuCallback callback){

        if(!callbacks.contains(callback)){
            callbacks.add(callback);
        }
        return;
    }

    public void removeCallback(MeuCallback callback){

        callbacks.remove(callback);
        return;
    }

    private void constroiSequenciaNumeros() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

                    //Percorre o ArrayList e chama imprimeNumero()
                    //em todos os callbaks registados.

                    for(MeuCallback meuCallback : calbacks) {
                        meuCallback.imprimeNumero(i);
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**NOTA:** Esta implementação pode provocar vazamento de memória se a classe que implementa MeuCallback for uma Activity/Fragment e estes sejam destruidos/recriados pelo Android, isso acontecerá, por exemplo, sempre que houver a rotação do dispositivo.
Para evitar essa situação use `minhaWorkerClass.removeCallback(this)` no método `onDestroy()`.
Note que há situações em que [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) pode não ser chamado.

Comment: ramaral, obrigado pela sua resposta, mas o seu resultado fica igual ao meu, ou seja, o Callback da MainActivity deixa de receber dados após ser aberta a SegundaAtivity. Tem outra solução?

Comment: Testei o código e ele funciona. Quando passo para a segunda Activity, como seria de esperar, são apresentados logs das duas activities.

Comment: Sim funciona perfeitamente. Tinha-me esquecido de aplicar o ciclo Foreach para percorrer os Callbacks. Muito obrigado.